# Pass Google API client object from activity to sliding tabs fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm trying to pass an object from an activity to a sliding tab fragment. I use a newInstance method with Bundle, Serializable and args in my fragment but my problem is how and where should i call this method. Thanks in advance.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

GoogleApiClient apiClient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


}
```

PageAdapter

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;


public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ValidTab tab1 = new ValidTab();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            ExpiredTab tab2 = new ExpiredTab();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            AllTab tab3 = new AllTab();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

ValidTab

```
public class ValidTab extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper db;
Button pick_buy_date, pick_exp_date, save, sync;
TextView buy_date, exp_date;
EditText et_name,et_shop,et_note;
int type;
private static final String DESCRIBABLE_KEY = "gapiclient";
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

public static ValidTab newInstance(GoogleApiClient gApiclient){
    ValidTab validTab = new ValidTab();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(DESCRIBABLE_KEY, (Serializable) gApiclient);
    validTab.setArguments(bundle);
    return validTab;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    googleApiClient = (GoogleApiClient) getArguments().getSerializable(DESCRIBABLE_KEY);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.valid_tab, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can Use it like this

```
final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(),apiClient );
```

And in pageradapter class

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient;
public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs,GoogleApiClient apiClient) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    this.apiClient=apiClient;
}
```

and

```
switch (position) {
        case 0:

            return ValidTab.newIntance(gApiclient);
        case 1:

            return ExpiredTab.newIntance(gApiclient);
        case 2:

            return AllTab.newIntance(gApiclient);
        default:
            return null;
    }
```

The Best Way is this

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    //instantiate object public static
    public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mContext)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mContext)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate()
    {
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

your Fragment class

```
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.valid_tab, container, false);
 googleApiClient = ApplicationTest.mGoogleApiClient;
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, i think your way is working but now i get an cannot cast error in line:
undle.putSerializable(DESCRIBABLE_KEY, (Serializable) gApiclient);
Any idea?

Comment: u need to do correct implementation of serializable

Comment: check the answer now

Comment: Ok, so base your update i shouldn't call newInstance method in PageAdapter class? Just return a ValidTab tab = new ValidTab() ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct place would be in your adapter's getItem() method -

```
ValidTab tab1 = new ValidTab();
//add arguments to fragment here
return tab1;
```

To get data in your Adapter, either pass it through the constructor when you initialise the adapter in the Activity or create a public method in your adapter and pass the through that method by calling it from your activity.